# Is OEIS A007018 really a subsequence of squarefree numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, oeis, integer-sequences, polynomials

A comment in [A007018 a(n) = a(n-1)^2 + a(n-1), a(0)=1](https://oeis.org/A007018) claims

> Subsequence of squarefree numbers (A005117). - Reinhard Zumkeller, Nov 15 2004

Is that really so?

As far as I know, it is an open problem if a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z[x]}$ of degree $\ge 5$ can be
squarefree infinitely often (some sources require $f$ to be irreducible).

If the OEIS comment is correct, the sequence will give an infinite family of 
(irreducible) polynomials which are squarefree infinitely often.

Denote by $a_n$ the terms of OEIS A007018. Set $a_n = x$ and $$f(x)=a_{n+4}=x \cdot (x + 1) \cdot (x^{2} + x + 1) \cdot (x^{4} + 2 x^{3} + 2 x^{2} + x + 1) \\\\ \cdot (x^{8} + 4 x^{7} + 8 x^{6} + 10 x^{5} + 9 x^{4} + 6 x^{3} + 3 x^{2} + x + 1)$$

$f(a_n)=a_{n+4}$ will be squarefree infinitely often (including the irreducible degree 8 factor) 
and iterating $x \mapsto x^2+x$ will produce an infinite family of polynomials with this property.

**Added** For references of squarefree values of polynomials, the search terms are *square free values of polynomials*. E.g. [here p.1](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa60/aa6032.pdf) and [here "11. Squarefree values of polynomials".](https://nitaj.users.lmno.cnrs.fr/abc.html)

Comment: Do you have a reference for that question, about some polynomials of high degree being squarefree infinitely often?


Comment: As noticed here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersSequence.html, it is not known whether all of them are square-free.

Comment: @Per edited the question. @Ilya the mathworld sequence is different from the sequence I am asking or am I missing something?

Comment: Sylvester’s sequence is your $a(n)+1$. Since $a(n)=a(n-1)(a(n-1)+1)$, your sequence consists of squarefree numbers if and only if Sylvester’s sequence does.

Comment: For the first 100 primes, the sequence becomes periodic modulo $p^2$ without passing through $0$. 

Comment: Hm, Mathworld only says that the sequence is squarefree for the first 10e15...

Comment: You can't ping two people in one comment, joro – only the first person gets notified when you try to do that.

Answer (score 7):

Prime factors below $10^{10}$ of $a_n$ can be found in [OEIS A007996](https://oeis.org/A007996), and I've tested that none of them divides $a_n$ when squared. Same was [reported by Andersen](http://primerecords.dk/sylvester-factors.htm) earlier for primes below $2^{32}$.

In fact, the divisibility by $p^2$ can be quickly disproved for many primes $p$ if one tries to unroll the sequence backwards starting with $a_n \equiv 0\pmod{p^2}$ for the smallest index $n$, thus giving $a_{n-1}\equiv -1\pmod{p^2}$. While this leads to solving a quadratic equation modulo $p^2$ with respect to $a_{n-2}$ and potentially can give two roots, in roughly half of the cases the equation will have no solutions. Then we solve a quadratic equation for $a_{n-3}$ and so on. On average this process stops within a constant number of steps without reaching $a_1\equiv 2\pmod{p^2}$ (meaning that $p^2$ cannot divide $a_n$).

Since solving quadratic equation (via computing square roots) modulo $p^2$ is relatively time-consuming, for "persistent" primes $p$ that survived a certain number of square-root computations it's worth to switch to direct computation of $a_n$ modulo $p^2$ until the zero residue or the period is encountered. I used the threshold of 100 square-root computations for this purpose. With this mixed strategy the search for prime divisors can be easily extended beyond $10^{10}$ if needed.

Comment: The roots modulo p^2 are 0 and p^2-1, right?

Comment: @joro: Yes, but zero is dropped if we assume that $n$ is the smallest index giving divisibility by $p^2$.

Comment: @joro: I've clarified this issue in the answer. In fact, I worked directly with the Sylvester sequence $a_n+1=a_{n+1}/a_n$, where all terms are co-prime.