# Does $a_0=6$, $a_{n+1} = (a_n-1)\cdot a_n\cdot (a_n+1)$ define a square-free sequence?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $a_0:=6$ and $a_{n+1} = (a_n-1)\cdot a_n\cdot (a_n+1)$.
Then $a_1 = 210 = 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7$.
What is the smallest value of $n$ for which $a_n$ is not square-free?

---

The congruent numbers are precisely the numbers that can be expressed as the square-free part of $x^3 - x$ where $x$ is a nonnnegative integer.

The sequence given contains some huge square-free numbers for low values of $n$.  I wonder how long that pattern continues.

Comment: What do you already know about this sequence? How did it arise?

Comment: A similar question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/118050 
Here it iterates $f(x) = x(x-1)(x+1)$, while there it deals with $f(x)=x(x+1)$.

Comment: Values $a(n)/a(n-1)$ are listed in https://oeis.org/A231831

Comment: I checked that for every prime $p<10^6$, this sequence doesn't vanish mod $p^2$.

Comment: Of course it doesn't matter, but why not start with $a(0)=2$?

Comment: I've checked that $p^2$ does not divide any terms for primes  $p<10^8$.

Comment: If we replace everything by $a(n+1)=a(n)^2+2a(n),a(0)=1$, then I can prove it's square free.

Comment: @DrorSpeiser. Notice that if $b(n)=a(n)/a(n-1)$ then $b$ satisfies $b(n)=b(n-1)^2-2b(n-1)+2$. Since $2^2-2\times 2+2=2$ is constant, all $b(n)$'s are pairwise coprime (if the first one is odd), and $a(n)=\prod_{i<=n}b(i)$. Exactly the same situation applies to the original question: here $b(n)=b(n-1)^3+b(n-1)^2-1$ (as pointed out by Max Alekseyev) , again pairwise coprime as $(-1)^3+(-1)^2-1=-1$, and again $a(n)$ is the product of all preceding $b(i)$'s. So, my point is: given such similarity in the two situations, it could be quite interesting if you posted your proof.

Comment: ...cont... The point about $2^2-2\times 2+2=2$ or $(-1)^3+(-1)^2-1=-1$ is that repeated applications of the recurrence formula produce each time $2$, or $-1$, plus a multiple of the starting value. This implies coprimality of all terms.

Comment: @DrorSpeiser So you can settle the open problem (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118050 and the references gives there) whether there are integral polynomials of degree $\ge5$ which assume infinitely many squarefree values?

Comment: Ah, I was too quick to pull the trigger. My sequence is the cumulative product of Fermat numbers, which are pairwise coprime, and for some reason I thought they are all square free. I don't know how to prove that actually :(

Answer (score 9):

The question is equivalent to asking whether $b(n):=\frac{a(n)}{a(n-1)}$ are squarefree. The sequence $b(n)$ is listed in [OEIS A231831](https://oeis.org/A231831) and satisfies the recurrence $b(n+1) = b(n)^3 + b(n)^2 - 1$ with $b(1)=3$. Its terms are pairwise coprime, implying that each prime divides at most one term.

Quite similarly to [my treatment](https://mathoverflow.net/q/335636) of Sylvester sequence, I have computed all primes $p$ below $10^{10}$ such that $p\mid b(n)$ for some $n$ (there are $16944$ such primes), and verified that $p^2\nmid b(n)$. The primes $p$ and corresponding indices $n$ are now listed in [OEIS A362250](https://oeis.org/A362250) and [OEIS A362251](https://oeis.org/A362251), respectively.

---

The question can also be analyzed heuristically by considering the map $x\mapsto x^3 + x^2 - 1$ modulo prime $p$ as random. Various kinds of statistics for such mappings and their functional graphs are given by [Flajolet and Odlyzko (1989)](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00075445). My very rough analysis suggests that the "probability" for prime $p$ to divide some $b(n)$ is proportional to $\frac1{p^{1/2}}$, and the "probability" for $p^2$ to divide some $b(n)$ is proportional to $\frac1{p^{3/2}}$. The latter means that one should expect only a finite number of primes $p$ with $p^2\mid b(n)$, if any exists at all.

---

There is a somewhat similar sequence [OEIS A231830](https://oeis.org/A231830) satisfying $c(n+1) = c(n)^3 - c(n)^2 + 1$ with $c(1)=5$. The above analysis applies to this sequence as well. **UPDATE**. I've confirmed that neither prime below $10^{10}$ (listed in [OEIS A362252](https://oeis.org/A362252)) divides its terms when squared.

Answer (score 3):

It is interesting to consider the dynamics of the map $f\colon x\mapsto x^3-x$  on the set $X=\mathbb{Z}/p^2$.  Let $C$ be the set of periodic points, i.e. those $x$ for which $f^n(x)=x$ for some $n>0$.  We can divide these into orbits $C_1,\dotsc,C_m$, starting with $C_1=\{0\}$. We can then put
$$ D_i=\{x\in X\setminus C: f^n(x)\in C_i\text{ for some } n > 0\}. $$
We find that $X=\coprod_{i=1}^mC_i\amalg\coprod_{i=1}^mD_i$.  The problem is to prove that $6\not\in D_1$.  If we put $Y=p\mathbb{Z}/p^2$ we find that for $y\in Y$ we have $f(y)=-y$ and thus $f^2(y)=y$.  This shows that $Y\subseteq C$.  Apart from this, experiment (with primes up to about 200) does not reveal any obvious regularities.  Sometimes there are many periodic orbits in $X\setminus Y$, sometimes there are only a few, and there does not seem to be any simple formula for the size of $D_1$.